# parse only needed line from file

Tags: regex, perl, parsing

How to parse only a line which has a word QUERY?
I tried:

```
my @strs  = loadf('ck.txt');    

while(1)
{
    my $str = shift @strs;
    if(!$str)   
    {
        exit;
    }
    if($str =~ /QUERY/)
    {
        ($cl) = $str =~ /QUERY: (.*?)/;
        open F, ">>go.txt";
        print F $cl;
        close F;    
    }
}




sub loadf {
    open (F, "<".$_[0]) or erroropen($_[0]);
    chomp(my @data = <F>);
    close F;
    return @data;
}
```

ck.txt:

```
22.11.2012 16:55:45 +02:00
IP: 99.992.92.992
QUERY: BANNER_LANG=ru; textext community-lang=ru
REFERER: http:/site.ru/827
AGENT: Opera/9.80 (Windows NT 6.0) Presto/2.12.388 Version/12.10

22.11.2012 16:55:44 +02:00
IP: 89.189.191.6
QUERY: BANNER_LANG=ru; text; community-lang=ru
REFERER: http:/site.ru/444
AGENT: Opera/9.80 (Windows NT 5.1; U; ru) Presto/2.10.289 Version/12.00
```

But it doesn't work=\­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­

Comment: "it doesn't work" is a popular, but sadly inadequate way to describe your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either remove the `?` to make it greedy or add `$` after the closing `)`

Eg

```
QUERY: (.*)
```

or

```
QUERY: (.*?)$
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem was the `(.*?)`. `?` makes the match non-greedy, so it will match as few characters as possible while still satisfying the regex.  In this case, that was always zero characters.

Also, your code can be simplified:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @strs  = ('BLAH', ' QUERY: foobarbaz', 'QUERY asdf');    

#open the file once: more efficient.
open my $file, '>>', 'go.txt' or die "Can't open file: $!";
for  my $str (@strs)
{
    #Perform all matching logic in one go.
    if($str =~ m/QUERY: (.*)/)
    {
        print {$file} $1;
    }
}
close $file;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are complicating things. Your problem can be solved with a one-liner:

```
perl -nlwe 'print if /^QUERY/' query.txt >> go.txt
```

You may consider removing the start of line anchor `^` from the regex if your data is irregular.

If you wish to remove the word `QUERY:` you can use this one-liner:

```
perl -nlwe 'print if s/^QUERY:\s*//' query.txt >> go.txt
```

The deparsed code for this one-liner is (edited for simplicity):

```
use warnings;                       # -w option: enable warnings
BEGIN { $/ = "\n"; $\ = "\n"; }     # -l option: handle line endings
while (<>) {                        # -n option: read input file or stdin
    chomp;                          # -l option again
    print $_ if s/^QUERY:\s+//;     # our code
}
```